# HTML Encoding a JSON Request body before binding to model in dotnet5 (dotnet core)

Tags: .net-core, model, json.net, asp.net-core-5.0

The requirement was to ensure that we HTML encode any of the deserialized properties to prevent an API client from sending in HTML and script tags which would then be stored in the database.
For example, the following JSON body should result in the title property being encoded once bound onto our model.I am referring this article

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-mvc-core-html-encoding-json-body

```
{
    "Title" : "<script>Something Nasty</script>",
    "Description" : "A long description.",**
    "Reference": "REF12345"
}
```

I am using the below article but its not working in dotnet5 as **JsonInputFormatter** is not supported in dotnet5.

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-mvc-core-html-encoding-json-body

it always throws the below error on the extension method

> Error: Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter' from assembly
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json

```
public static class MvcOptionsExtensions
{
    public static void UseHtmlEncodeJsonInputFormatter(this MvcOptions opts, ILogger<MvcOptions> logger, ObjectPoolProvider objectPoolProvider)
    {
        opts.InputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonInputFormatter>();
 
        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new HtmlEncodeContractResolver()
        };
 
        var jsonInputFormatter = new JsonInputFormatter(logger, serializerSettings, ArrayPool<char>.Shared, objectPoolProvider);
 
        opts.InputFormatters.Add(jsonInputFormatter);
    }
}
```

Below is the code from **ConfigureServices** method (startup.cs) where i am using **NewtonsoftJson** instead of default **System.Text.Json**

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var logger = sp.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
            var objectPoolProvider = sp.GetService<ObjectPoolProvider>();
            string customViewLocation = Configuration["CommonPath"];
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
 options.UseHtmlEncodeJsonInputFormatter(logger.CreateLogger<MvcOptions>(), objectPoolProvider);
            }).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(options => options.FileProviders.Add(
        new PhysicalFileProvider(Configuration["CommonPath"]))).AddNewtonsoftJson((x =>
         x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
         ));
```

> Remaining code removed

Comment: `HTML Encoding a JSON Request body before binding to model in dotnet5`Maybe you can try to use a [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: ca you provide any code example please?